Is it correct to bind UDP and TCP sockets to the same address and handle them simultaneously?
I am trying to bind both UDP and TCP sockets to the same IP address and port, and then handle both types of connections. I have implemented the following code:
The main function initializes both sockets and uses poll() to monitor them:
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr = derive_sockaddr(argv[1], argv[2]);

    int server_socket = setup_server_socket(addr, SOCK_STREAM);
    int server_socket_udp = setup_server_socket(addr, SOCK_DGRAM);

    struct pollfd sockets[2] = {
        {.fd = server_socket, .events = POLLIN},
        {.fd = server_socket_udp, .events = POLLIN}
    };

    struct connection_state state = {0};
    while (true) {
        int ready = poll(sockets, sizeof(sockets) / sizeof(sockets[0]), -1);
        if (ready == -1) {
            perror("poll");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(sockets) / sizeof(sockets[0]); i++) {
            if (sockets[i].revents != POLLIN) {
                continue;
            }
            int s = sockets[i].fd;

            if (s == server_socket_udp) {
                // Handle UDP
            } else if (s == server_socket) {
                int connection = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
                if (connection == -1 && errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                    close(server_socket);
                    perror("accept");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else {
                    connection_setup(&state, connection);
                    sockets[0].events = 0;
                    sockets[1].fd = connection;
                    sockets[1].events = POLLIN;
                }
            } else {
                assert(s == state.sock);
                bool cont = handle_connection(&state);
                if (!cont) {
                    sockets[0].events = POLLIN;
                    sockets[1].fd = -1;
                    sockets[1].events = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Here’s the helper function for setting up the sockets:
static int setup_server_socket(struct sockaddr_in addr, int type) {
    const int enable = 1;
    const int backlog = 1;

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, type, 0);
    if (sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(enable)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (type == SOCK_DGRAM) {
        int broadcast = 1;
        if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof(broadcast)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST)");
            close(sock);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        close(sock);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "UDP or TCP socket bound to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    }

    if (type == SOCK_STREAM) {
        if (listen(sock, backlog)) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return sock;
}

All the other functions work properly it is just the logic im not sure about:
Is it correct and safe to bind both UDP and TCP sockets to the same address and port?
Does the poll() logic properly handle these sockets? Specifically, can I rely on poll() to monitor and differentiate between the TCP connection, the UDP socket, and incoming data?
Are there potential issues or race conditions in the code when switching between handling a UDP socket, accepting a TCP connection, and processing the TCP client connection?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Besides IP address and port number, the protocol type (e.g. TCP or UDP) is part of what makes a connection unique. So you can bind both a TCP and a UDP socket to the same interface with the same port number. The difference come when you poll and want to process input from the sockets, where they need to processed differently.

Despite the same number, a UDP port is not the same as a TCP port (or an SCTP or DCCP port).

thank you for your answer! But what exactly does this mean?

A port number is a table address for a protocol to point to look up the process that reserved that port number for that protocol. See this answer and this answer about that.

"both types of connections" There is no connection if you use UDP. You only have unrelated datagrams. They can arrive out of order and some may be lost as well.

But can I stilll use a poll fd struct array to track the udp socket and the tcp socket, like I've done in my code?

The set of UDP ports is completely separate from the set of TCP ports.
So there's no problem having one socket with TCP port n open and another with UDP port n open.

So can I handle them the same way? or do I have to check for a different socket as the socket in my code?

@checkchecker Yes it's fine.  The poll function can handle multiple different sockets of differing types.  That one is TCP port n and another is UDP port n doesn't matter.

alright thank you!

@checkchecker But you need to remember that TCP and UDP work differently. TCP is a stream protocol, there are no message boundaries, so no direct correspondence between calls to send()/write() and recv()/read(). UDP is a datagram protocol, so each message sent corresponds to a single message received.
